# Post facebook feed picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbjs

I am using FB JS-SDK `FB.ui` feed to post on Facebook but I am having issue with the picture I am posting. What I need is that the picture should look like the picture in image linked here (rectangular shape might be 84x48). 
[image: colors picture in left of post]

But when I post the picture it is cropped and appears in square shape (200x200). Its original dimension is 800x400 approx near to the Facebook's images ratio i.e. 1.91:1

Comment: Thanks for editing, any resolution!

Comment: you should try using the share dialog instead of the feed dialog.

Comment: already tried that but no change